# type arguments not allowed on Self type

Tags: rust, types

I need to define a trait that change the type of an internal attribute of a struct. But the main struct type must be same. As an example, if I bound this trait to `Foo<A>` the trait method should return a `Foo<B>`. Not `Bar<B>`.

I could do it like below. But users have to manually define the return type. I think we can detect the return type statically without letting users to do it.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0d422e9eb39a5668eb43fea26cd7fb9f)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

trait StorageId: PartialEq + Eq + Hash {}

struct MyEntity<SI: StorageId> {
    avatar_image: SI,
    other_field: String
}

trait CurrentReplaceStorageId<TO: StorageId> {
    type From: StorageId;
    
    type Output;
    
    fn replace_storage_id<'a>(self, values: &'a mut HashMap<Self::From, TO>) -> Self::Output;
}

impl <F: StorageId, T: StorageId> CurrentReplaceStorageId<T> for MyEntity<F> {
    type From = F;
    
    // Users have to define this line.
    type Output = MyEntity<T>;
    
    fn replace_storage_id<'a>(self, values: &'a mut HashMap<Self::From, T>) -> Self::Output {
        MyEntity {
            avatar_image: values.remove(&self.avatar_image).unwrap(),
            other_field: self.other_field
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it without an extra return type. But I could not find any way to do it.
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9045c0367f26bd19922c80e0cd10d239)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

trait StorageId: PartialEq + Eq + Hash {}

struct MyEntity<SI: StorageId> {
    avatar_image: SI,
    other_field: String
}

trait ExpectedReplaceStorageId<TO: StorageId> {
    type From: StorageId;
    
    fn replace_storage_id<'a>(self, values: &'a mut HashMap<Self::From, TO>) -> Self<TO>;
}

impl <F: StorageId, T: StorageId> ExpectedReplaceStorageId<T> for MyEntity<F> {
    type From = F;
    
    fn replace_storage_id<'a>(self, values: &'a mut HashMap<Self::From, T>) -> Self<T> {
        MyEntity {
            avatar_image: values.remove(&self.avatar_image).unwrap(),
            other_field: self.other_field
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think we can detect the return type statically without letting users to do it.

Unfortunately, this is false. Your users will have to specify the type.

Doing that would require Higher-Kinded Types, which Rust does not support.